# Backbone (Parse.com) collection add ignoring duplicates

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform

I'm using **Parse.com** Javascript API (*Backbone*).

I'm trying to `add` a `Query` result (array of models) to a `collection`, but I'm getting this error: `Duplicate id: can't add the same model to a collection twice.`

### Sample:

```
var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("GameScore");

// A Collection containing all instances of TestObject.
var TestCollection = Parse.Collection.extend({
  model: GameScore
});
var collection = new TestCollection();


var query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);
query.equalTo("playerName", "Dan Stemkoski");
query.find({
  success: function(results) {
    collection.add(results);
  },
  error: function(error) {}
});
```

### Question:

It is possible to call add method ignoring duplicates models ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save both models you should change (see http://underscorejs.org/#uniqueId) or remove ID property from the fetched models.
If you want to replace duplicated models with fetched you should use http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-update. Or if you want to replace all your old data you should use http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-reset

Comment: Finally, parse.collection has not update  method, I should to implement it calling remove+add . Thanks for your oriantarion

Answer (score 1):

This is because Parse.com Javascript API is based on an older version of backbone. Newer backbone versions silently skip duplicate models being added to a collection.

You can simply replace / augment the Parse collection.add() method with the newer backbone version.

I used underscore to extend my Parse Collection with the new methods I required.

For example, to fix the issue when adding duplicate models to a collection, I added the newer version of collection.add() as so:

_.extend(selectedUsersCol, newBackboneAddMethod());
Where newBackboneAddMethod() is a copy of the add method from a new version of Backbone/Underscore.

See this answer on parse.com: https://www.parse.com/questions/what-version-of-backbone-is-parse-javascript-api-based-on